# how load many photos from url in background (asynchronous)

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, uiimageview, nsurlconnection, nsurl

i have this method i use to load many images to scroll view, but when the images load from the url my scroll view is stuck and i can't understand how to load them in the background so the user will not feel it.

**this method will call few times (8) in "for" cycle.**

```
- (void)loadPhotosToLeftscroll{

    //getting image information from JSON
    NSMutableDictionary *photoDict;
    photoDict = [leftPhotoArray lastObject];

    //getting the photo
    NSString *photoPath = [photoDict objectForKey:@"photos_path"];
    NSLog(@"photo Path:%@",photoPath);


    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoPath]];    

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            // use the image how you like, say, as your button background

            //calculating the hight of next photo
            UIImageView *leftImage = [leftBlockScroll.subviews lastObject];

            //allocating photoView
            UIImageView *photoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5 , leftImage.frame.origin.y + leftImage.frame.size.height+5, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2 )];
            photoView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [photoView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [photoView.layer setCornerRadius:3];


            //getting items list
            NSDictionary *sh_items = [photoDict objectForKey:@"items"];

            //adding image button
            UIButton *imageOverButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imageOverButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, photoView.frame.size.width, photoView.frame.size.height);
            [imageOverButton addTarget:self action:@selector(LeftimagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imageOverButton setTag:[leftPhotoArray count]-1];
            [photoView addSubview:imageOverButton];

            //adding sh button to imageView
            [self addThe_sh_signs:sh_items To_ImageView:photoView];

            //subViewing the image to the scrollView
            [self insert_Image:image toImageView:photoView in_Scroll:leftBlockScroll];

            //calclulating the position of next imageView in scroll.
            nextLeftPhotoHight = photoView.frame.size.height + photoView.frame.origin.y + 5;

            //calculating the hight of the highest scroll view in both.
            leftBlockScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(160, [self theSizeOfScrollViewHight]);
            rightBlocScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(160, [self theSizeOfScrollViewHight]);
            isLoadindContant = NO;
            [self.view reloadInputViews];
            [leftBlockScroll reloadInputViews];

}
```

please do not send me to some link that trying to explain how to use the asynchronous.
Try to explain according the method you see here. 
**Im here for any question, that you need to ask to help me.**

Comment: I'm pretty sure the way you're doing it explicates "foreground" loading.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do it asynchronously in a proper way. I do not think there is any way around that. I subclassed an UIImageView object and placed many instances of it within the cells of a talbe (in your case within the scroll view). The subclass objects are initialized with an url and load their image asynchronously (with some caching so that the image is not loaded every time).

This tutorial helped me much in the beginning: 
http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

You will just have to adopt that to your scroll view. The underlaying principle remains the same.